# Will cisco 3750-e switches run the old ipservices ios code?

Tags: router, switch, cisco, ios

was wondering about cisco 3750-e switches. Will they run the old ipservices ios code? Or do they only run the univeral image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750e_3560e/software/release/12.2_52_se/release/notes/OL19707.html), they do not support it.